# how to check if Today's date = date from sql?

Tags: php, sql

This ...

```
$sql = "select rejster_date from date";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) == date("Y-m-d") ){ 

    Code 
}
```

... only checks the first column of the Table, but I want to check all columns of the table.

Comment: You should not be using the `mysql_*` extensions anymore, they are deprecated.

Comment: `select * from table where something='something'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must mean first row?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   if ($row['rester_date'] == date("Y-m-d") ){ 
     // ... do other staffs
   }
}
```

You could also make things easier by modifying the query.  Won't fetch unnecessary records.

```
$sql = "select rejster_date from date where rester_date = '".date("Y-m-d")."'";
```

Also, `mysql_query` is out.  Use `mysqli_query`.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: rejster_date not rester_date (in the where ^^). U also could use `now()` if its a datetime field